# React-dnd component library

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-dnd

Edits>>>

Edit::I created an example on git for clarity https://github.com/suityou01/wgas

EditEdit::Possible duplicate of this unanswered question from 12 months ago
[Is there a way to share React.context between packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428503/is-there-a-way-to-share-react-context-between-packages)

EditEditEdit::Added a commit to demonstrate the use of what I am currently calling "React Context Provider Value Chaining"

See the screenshot below
[image]

So this is using a react context created in the top level package, and a nested context in the sub package with a shared value

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <CustomContext.Provider value={sharedValue}>
      <SubCustomContext.Provider value={sharedValue}>
        <SamePackageExampleComponent/>
        <ExampleComponent />
      </SubCustomContext.Provider>
    </CustomContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

<<<Edits

I am trying to create a react component library that uses react-dnd as a peer dependency.

In my application, that imports the library and its components, the components are wrapped in a DND Provider.

When I run it I get

`Expected drag drop context`

So it is as if the provider context is not available in the component in the package.

It works if I use a component created in the local application.

So the project structure looks like

```
package.json (With react, react-dnd and html5backend as dev dependencies)
  /src/index.js (This imports component.js and wraps it in a dnd-provider)
  /package/package.json
  /package/component.js <-- The context is not available in this component
```

This is the code in the app

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <SortedList data={json} />
    </DndProvider>
  )
}
```

This is the component code

```
export function SortedListItem(props){

  const { data } = props
  const [{ opacity }, dragRef] = useDrag(
      () => ({
        type: "CARD",
        item: "1",
        collect: (monitor) => ({
          opacity: monitor.isDragging() ? 0.5 : 1
        })
      }),
      []
    )
  return (
      <div ref={dragRef} >
          <li>{data.name}</li>
          {props.children}
      </div>
  )
}
```

If the component is part of my tree, why is the context not available if the top level of the tree is wrapped?

Comment: Can you provide the `package.json` of your application and the one of your component package?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wF4Jxwcd

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tHSuRXRt

Comment: Can you also provide the 2nd `package.json`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Dm5aU3QB

Comment: I made an example and posted to github, see here https://github.com/suityou01/wgas